# On click() list item, show div with same ID

Tags: jquery

I have a menu with list items whose ID is associated to a div, each containing content relative to the list items. I am trying to show the content when a particular list item is clicked. I realize the `this` is referring to `#agency ul li`, but I can't seem to get my head around how to reference the content divs.

HTML

```
<ul id="agency">
            <li>Select an Agency</li>
            <ul>
                <li id="agriculture">Department of Agriculture</li>
                <li id="commerce">Department of Commerce</li>
                <li id="defense">Department of Defense</li>
                <li id="energy">Department of Energy</li>
                <li id="health">Department of Health and Human Services</li>
                <li id="homeland">Department of Homeland Security</li>
                <li id="interior">Department of the Interior</li>
                <li id="transportation">Department of Transportation</li>
                <li id="veterans">Department of Veteran Affairs</li>
                <li id="epa">Environmental Protection Agency</li>
                <li id="aeronautics">Nat'l Aeronautics and Space Admin</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>

    <div id="agency-wrap">
        <div id="agriculture">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.ars.usda.gov/partnering">USDA Agricultural Research Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.ars.usda.gov/business/docs.htm?docid=763&page=3">USDA ARS Tech Transfer Coordinators</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.fs.fed.us">USDA Forest Service</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="commerce">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.nist.gov/tpo/">DOC Nat'l Institue of Standards and Tech</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.noaa.gov">DOC Nat'l Ocean and Atmosph Admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.its.bldrdoc.gov/">DOC Institue for Telecom Sciences</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.nist.gov/mep/">DOC Manufacturing Extension Program</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="defense">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.acq.osd.mil/ott/techtransit">DOD Secretary of Defense</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.arl.army.mil/main/Main/default.cfm?Action=6">DOD Army Research Lab</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.onr.navy.mil/en/Sciecne-Technology/Directtorates/Transition/Technology-Transfer-T2aspx">DOD Office Naval Research</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.wpafb.af.mil/library/factsheets/factsheet.asp?id=6026">DOD Air Force Research Lab</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.mda.mil/business/tech_apps.html">DOD Missle Defense Agency</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.jfcom.mil/about/industry.htm">DOD Joint Forces</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.defenseinnovationmarketplace.mil/index.html">DOD Defense Innovation Marketplace</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="energy">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://technologytransfer.energy.gov">DOE Tech Transfer Office</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="health">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.ott.nih.gov/">DHHS National Institutes of HealthNIH </a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cdc.gov/od/ads/techtran/tech.htm">DHHS Centers for Disease Control</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.fda.gov/ScienceResearch/CollaborativeOpportunities/default.htm">DHHS Food and Drug Administration</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>​
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('#agency-wrap > div').addClass('agency-hide');

    $('#agency ul li').click(function() {
        $("#" + $(this).attr('id')).fadeIn('slow').siblings().hide();
    });
});​
```

CSS

```
.agency-hide {
    display: none;
}        
#agency {
    width: 300px;
}​
```

I have not styled the css yet and will take care of that after functionality is complete

http://jsfiddle.net/yD4D5/

Comment: Id's in the page should be unique.. try using a class instead

Comment: Please also include the code in your question.

Comment: Post supporting code here instead of directing to an external link. fiddle is good, but it is better if you have the actual code here. Btw, I clicked your fiddle like 2 mins back and it is still loading..

Comment: sorry, first offense. does it really require a negative?

Comment: jsFiddle seems to be down ATM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a element with id , the selector engine assumes there is only 1 single ID as this supposed to be unique.. Thats the reason you see this behaviour..

Try replacing the the id with class and change the selector to this

```
$("." + $(this).data("id")).fadeIn('slow').siblings().hide();
```

It should work fine..

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/yD4D5/2/)

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('#agency-wrap > div').addClass('agency-hide');

    $('#agency ul li').click(function() {
        $("." + $(this).attr('id')).fadeIn('slow').siblings().hide();
    });
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="agency">
            <li>Select an Agency</li>
            <ul>
                <li id="agriculture">Department of Agriculture</li>
                <li id="commerce">Department of Commerce</li>
                <li id="defense">Department of Defense</li>
                <li id="energy">Department of Energy</li>
                <li id="health">Department of Health and Human Services</li>
                <li id="homeland">Department of Homeland Security</li>
                <li id="interior">Department of the Interior</li>
                <li id="transportation">Department of Transportation</li>
                <li id="veterans">Department of Veteran Affairs</li>
                <li id="epa">Environmental Protection Agency</li>
                <li id="aeronautics">Nat'l Aeronautics and Space Admin</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>

    <div id="agency-wrap">
        <div class="agriculture">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.ars.usda.gov/partnering">USDA Agricultural Research Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.ars.usda.gov/business/docs.htm?docid=763&page=3">USDA ARS Tech Transfer Coordinators</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.fs.fed.us">USDA Forest Service</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="commerce">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.nist.gov/tpo/">DOC Nat'l Institue of Standards and Tech</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.noaa.gov">DOC Nat'l Ocean and Atmosph Admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.its.bldrdoc.gov/">DOC Institue for Telecom Sciences</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.nist.gov/mep/">DOC Manufacturing Extension Program</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="defense">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.acq.osd.mil/ott/techtransit">DOD Secretary of Defense</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.arl.army.mil/main/Main/default.cfm?Action=6">DOD Army Research Lab</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.onr.navy.mil/en/Sciecne-Technology/Directtorates/Transition/Technology-Transfer-T2aspx">DOD Office Naval Research</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.wpafb.af.mil/library/factsheets/factsheet.asp?id=6026">DOD Air Force Research Lab</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.mda.mil/business/tech_apps.html">DOD Missle Defense Agency</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.jfcom.mil/about/industry.htm">DOD Joint Forces</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.defenseinnovationmarketplace.mil/index.html">DOD Defense Innovation Marketplace</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="energy">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://technologytransfer.energy.gov">DOE Tech Transfer Office</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="health">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.ott.nih.gov/">DHHS National Institutes of HealthNIH </a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.cdc.gov/od/ads/techtran/tech.htm">DHHS Centers for Disease Control</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.fda.gov/ScienceResearch/CollaborativeOpportunities/default.htm">DHHS Food and Drug Administration</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>​
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not use same id for two elements in same document.

save id of corresponding `div` in `data` of each `li` as

`<li data-id="agriculture">Department of Agriculture</li>`

in js

```
 $('#agency ul li').click(function() {
        $("#" + $(this).data("id")).fadeIn('slow').siblings().hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a different ID for the div. The ID has to be unique as its name suggests. This is why you cannot access the div as its ID is not unique.